# Random Number Generator in Python

Tags: python, random, numbers, generator

just started learning Python(2) and was wondering what the best way to make a Random Number Generator. I have made a very basic one so far with:

```py
import random

for x in range(1):
    print random.randint(0,5)
```

I was wondering if there was a better way to do this with the ability to have numbers that are not integers generated. The end goal for this code is to make a random period of time pass in a game using `time.sleep(x)`, would love to know if there is a better way of doing this.

Comment: As an aside, you really should be learning Python 3. Python 3 came out over a decade ago, and Python 2 is officially passed its end of life.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use random.unform:

```
def rand(start,end):
    return random.uniform(start,end)
```

or if you don't like random.uniform:

```
def rand(start,end):
    return random.random()*(end-start)+start
```